# SQL to combine and flatten table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, flatten

In MySQL, I have three tables that look like:

USERS:

```
USER_ID | USERNAME
1       | Homer Simpson
```

FIELDS:

```
FIELD_ID | FIELD_NAME
1        | Phone
2        | Address
```

FIELD_VALUES:

```
USER_ID | FIELD_ID | FIELD_VALUE
1       | 1        | 555-1212
1       | 2        | 10 biteme drive
```

And what I am wanting to do is combine the three tables so that I end up with one row for each user, with field names as column headers and the field values, so I end up with:

USERS_TABLE:

```
USER_ID  | USER_NAME     | PHONE    | ADDRESS
1        | Homer Simpson | 555-1212 | 10 biteme drive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If field names (phone and address) are fixed, you could use this trick to pivot your data:

```
SELECT
  users.user_id,
  users.user_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field_id=1 THEN field_value END) AS Phone,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field_id=2 THEN field_value END) AS Address
FROM
  users INNER JOIN field_values
  ON users.user_id = field_values.user_id
GROUP BY
  users.user_id,
  users.user_name
```

but if your values are not fixed, you need to use a dynamic query:

```
SELECT    
  CONCAT(    
    'SELECT users.user_id,users.username,',    
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN field_id=', field_id, ' THEN field_value END) AS `', field_name, '`')),    
    ' FROM users INNER JOIN field_values ON users.user_id = field_values.user_id',
    ' GROUP BY users.user_id, users.username')    
FROM `fields` INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a41269/1).

Answer (score 0):

try the following : -
`SELECT
  users.user_id,username,  fv1.field_value value1, innertab.field_value value2
FROM
  USERS LEFT JOIN FIELD_VALUES fv1
  ON users.user_id = fv1.user_id
INNER JOIN FIELDS f1
ON fv1.FIELD_ID = f1.FIELD_ID AND f1.FIELD_ID = 1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
  users.user_id, FIELD_VALUES.field_value
FROM
  USERS LEFT JOIN FIELD_VALUES
  ON users.user_id = FIELD_VALUES.user_id
INNER JOIN FIELDS
ON FIELD_VALUES.FIELD_ID = FIELDS.FIELD_ID AND FIELDS.FIELD_ID = 2) AS innertab ON
innertab.user_id = users.user_id`

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0097b4/31)